# mmap only needed pages of kernel buffer to user space

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770582/1284631

I need something similar, but without having to allocate a buffer: the buffer is large, in theory, but the user space program only needs to access some parts of it, so a limited number of pages.

The question is:

What would be the body of the `my_vm_ops.fault()` method and what page to return through `vmf->page`? (it needs to allocate the needed page, but not from a pre-existing buffer)

Comment: If you don't allocate the buffer, where does it come from?

Comment: @CL. Well, the idea would be to allocate just the pages that are asked for. Do you suggest that for each page fault I should create a buffer with vmalloc_user() of exactly one PAGE_SIZE and, then, return that page to the vmf->page field? Basically, the my_fault() function should be like: {void *my_buf = vmalloc_user(PAGE_SIZE); vmf->page=vmalloc_to_page(my_buf); get_page(vmf->page);} ? What to do then with vmf->pgoff? Does it still has any meaning? PS Thank you.

Comment: @CL. I think this is the answer, indeed: static int my_fault(struct vm_area_struct *vma, struct vm_fault *vmf){void *my_buf = vmalloc_user(PAGE_SIZE); vmf->page=vmalloc_to_page(my_buf); vmf->page=get_page(vmf->page);}. Could you confirm this, pls?

    return 0;
}

Comment: What kind of memory do you need? Why can't the application allocate it?

Comment: @CL. It is an embedded Linux: no swap, and only 1GB of RAM. I need to fake (virtualize) memory/registers spread over 256 MB of RAM, that I simply have no room for. Is there any method to get_page() a page only if was not previously allocated?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is already possible by calling [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

Alternatively, call `mmap` on `/dev/zero`.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot modify the user-space program.

Comment: But can you make a symbolic link to `/dev/zero`?

Comment: I am able to create a symbolic link to /dev/zero, indeed. How should I further proceed?

Comment: The program is looking for some /dev/uiox device, that I am able to make it pointing towards /dev/zero instead. However, if the program mmap() the file (that is /dev/zero), it won't need as much memory to allocate? Does mmap() only allocate pages on demand? And, if yes, how could I emulate the same behavior inside my vmf->fault() method?